# change the formatting of the chapter

Tags: sectioning, formatting, chapters

I am trying to change the formatting of my chapter. The class i am using is report. I want it to be bold centered. I used the following but no effect. .

```
\renewcommand{\@makechapterhead}[1]{%
\vspace*{50\p@}%
{\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
\hrule
\vspace{5pt}%
\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
\huge\scshape \@chapapp\space \thechapter
\par\nobreak
\vskip 20\p@
\fi
\interlinepenalty\@M
\Huge \scshape #1\par
\vspace{5pt}%
\hrule
\nobreak
\vskip 40\p@
}}
\renewcommand{\@makeschapterhead}[1]{%
\vspace*{50\p@}%
{\parindent \z@ \raggedright
\normalfont
\hrule
\vspace{5pt}%
\interlinepenalty\@M
\Huge \scshape #1\par
\vspace{5pt}%
\hrule
\nobreak
\vskip 40\p@
}}
```

Comment: I'd recommend using the [`sectsty`](http://ctan.org/pkg/sectsty) package.

Comment: You only said that you want the chapter titles to be boldfaced and centered (and my answer shows one option to achieve this), but your code shows some rules and additional formatting. What exactly is the format you are looking for?

Comment: My real problem is not on how to achieve the formating. but whatever change i make in makechapterhead is not being applied in my document. However, when i execute the example of Mr.Micro from scratch it works!What might be the problem>?

Answer (score 4):

As suggested in a comment, you can use the [`sectsty`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/sectsty) package:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate some text

\chapterfont{\centering}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test Chapter}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The following MWE takes your code as the starting basis. I've provided examples of both numbered and unnumbered chapter headings. The main changes, relative to the code you provided, are: (i) the two `\raggedright` directives have been replaced with `\centering` directives, (ii) the three `\scshape` instructions have been replaced with `\bfseries` instructions, and (iii) there's a little bit more vertical whitespace below the first `\hrule` and above the second `\hrule` statements. (Your code provides only `5pt` of vertical separation, but I think that `12pt` and `10pt`, respectively, may be easier on the reader's eye. This is obviously a subjective decision and you should feel free to tweak the code further.) Hope this is what you're looking for.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for filler text
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@makechapterhead}[1]{%
    \vspace*{50\p@}%
    {\parindent \z@ \centering \normalfont
    \hrule
    \vspace{12pt}%
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
        \huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter
        \par\nobreak
        \vskip 20\p@
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries #1\par
    \vspace{10pt}%
    \hrule
    \vskip 40\p@
}}
\renewcommand{\@makeschapterhead}[1]{%
    \vspace*{50\p@}%
    {\parindent \z@ \centering
    \normalfont
    \hrule
    \vspace{12pt}%
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries #1\par
    \vspace{10pt}%
    \hrule
    \vskip 40\p@
}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\chapter{Hello There!}
\lipsum[1]
\chapter*{Good Bye}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

First the numbered chapter style:

[image]

Second, the unnumbered chapter style:

[image]